# How to add a GeoJSON layer in GraphHopper?

Tags: leaflet, geojson, graphhopper

I have a GeoJSON file containing POIs that I'd like to be able to display within a separate GraphHopper layer. After several tries and search over internet, I just can't manage to get a way to do it.

This is a sample of the GeoJSON file (I checked the whole file with JSON validator and it was OK).

> {"type": "Feature",
>    "properties": {
>       "fee": "no",
>       "bicycle_parking": "anchors",
>       "ref": "PVNAN23",
>       "address": "Rue Gabriel Goudy 44200 Nantes",
>       "name": "Pirmil P+R",
>       "capacity": "24",
>       "park_ride": "yes",
>       "amenity": "bicycle_parking",
>       "covered": "yes"
>   },
>   "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-1.5406709, 47.1960031]}},
>   {"type": "Feature",
>   "properties": {
>       "bicycle_parking": "stands",
>       "addr:postcode": "44000",
>       "addr:country": "FR",
>       "name": "Madeleine",
>       "capacity": "6",
>       "amenity": "bicycle_parking",
>       "addr:street": "chaussée de la Madeleine",
>       "note": "vérifié",
>       "addr:city": "Nantes",
>       "covered": "no",
>       "addr:housenumber": "35"
>   },
>   "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [-1.55076671448, 47.21000114109]}}
>
> ]}

I tried what is explained in [How to load external geojson file into leaflet map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/how-to-load-external-geojson-file-into-leaflet-map) but I cannot get it working.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON is valid that doesn't mean you're working with a valid GeoJSON object. For instance: `{"foo": "bar"}` is perfectly valid JSON but in no way a valid GeoJSON object. L.GeoJSON, leaflet's GeoJSON layer expects a FeatureCollection or an array containing Features.

A valid FeatureCollection:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": 1
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [0,0]
        }
    },{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "id": 2
        },
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [1,1]
        }
    }]
}
```

Or just the array with features:

```
[{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0,0]
    }
},{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
        "id": 2
    },
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [1,1]
    }
}]
```

(Note that just an array of features isn't a valid GeoJSON object but Leaflet will handle it without problems)

To load these into a L.GeoJson layer you'll need to make them available in your script. You could simple declare the object before you create the layer. For example:

```
// Declare GeoJSON object
var geojson = {
    type: "FeatureCollection",
    features: [
        // Features here
    ]
}

// Create a new GeoJSON layer with geojson object
// And add to map (assuming your map instance is assigned to "map")
var layer = new L.GeoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
```

But that will become quite a mess when you've got lots of features and it's always better to keep your logic and data separated so you should put your data object in a separate file. So let's say you've got the object stored in a file called "geo.json", then you can load the file with XHR/AJAX solution of your choice. I'm using jQuery in the following example:

```
// Fetch geo.json file and assign the data to geojson variable
$.getJSON('geo.json', function (geojson) {
    // Create a new GeoJSON layer with GeoJSON object
    // And add to map (assuming your map instance is assigned to "map")
    var layer = new L.GeoJSON(geojson).addTo(map);
});
```

Here a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mh8p4F?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I copied your code and pasted it at the end of the GraphHoper min.'s script file.

Unfortunately it is not rendering, the POIs are not even available in the layers.

I copied and pasted the geoson code as this in Plunker and it works well, so at least the geoson file is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm not familiar with Graphhopper, i tryed to take a look but their API is behind registration :(

Comment: No you can download freely the code, there https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/tree/0.3 and there https://graphhopper.com/#community Just go in Community.

Comment: Yes, i found the actual sourcecode, but it doesn't have documentation or any wiki. I was looking for documentation/reference but from what i've seen now this is really not my cup of tea. From what i've seen so far, I think GH is not as extendible as you would like. Maybe you could try to raise an issue on their tracker.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, I will follow your advise and will see. If there are any solutions, i will post the answer here in case other people would be interested in.

Comment: GraphHopper Maps is using Leaflet so the code should work. And the documentation is referenced in the main page (get started) https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/ or https://graphhopper.com/#community